# wordpress plugin link to php file

Tags: php, wordpress, url, post

Seems like a simple question, I'm building a simple contact form plugin for wordpress. I have the following line in a file called contact.php - this file is what creates the html elements for the form:

```
<form method="post" action="process.php" name="contactform" id="contactform">
```

However, process.php is not found (as it links to [here](http://www.mydomainname.com/process.php)). How do I link to that file using a php command, something like this perhaps:

```
<form method="post" action="<?php plugins_url(); ?>process.php" 
                           name="contactform" id="contactform">
```

The above doesn't work, but it's the kind of solution I'm looking for.

Comment: Where, relative to your website root folder, is your process.php file located?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use the below code. This will help you.

```
<form method="post" action="<?php plugins_url( 'process.php', __FILE__ ); ?>" name="contactform" id="contactform">
```